# PyThon: winrm [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Tags: python-3.x, winrm

I have the below simple code that tries to connect one windows machine which I can able to connct using rdp(remote desktop) of windows

But in python using pywinrm I got the below error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.XX.XX.XX', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001F44F92A6D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

I have the blow code

```
import winrm
session = winrm.Session('10.XX.XX.XX', auth=('admin','xxxxxx'), transport='ntlm', server_cert_validation='ignore') ##works
is_shell=True 
while is_shell:
    is_dir_get_or_create = session.run_cmd(r'if exist "C:\Temp\" (echo yes) else (echo no && mkdir C:\Temp)') ##failed
    is_shell=False
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure Remote Management is enabled on your system. As well as, if its secure only then 5986 will work , else it will be on 5985.

Comment: yes i tried 5985 as well same error

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solved it so you need to setup winrm quickconfigure into the destination hosts before connect it using winrm using python above code

So The below you have to do in destination hosts

```
C:/> winrm qc

WinRM is not set up to receive requests on this machine.
The following changes must be made:
 
Set the WinRM service type to delayed auto start.
 
Make these changes [y/n]? y
 
WinRM has been updated to receive requests.
 
WinRM service type changed successfully.
WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
The following changes must be made:
 
Create a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this machine.
Enable the WinRM firewall exception.
Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.
 
Make these changes [y/n]? y
 
WinRM has been updated for remote management.
 
Created a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this machine.
WinRM firewall exception enabled.
Configured LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.
```

And you can later disable it also

```
PS> Stop-Service winrm
PS> Set-Service -Name winrm -StartupType Disabled
```

That resolved the above error